# How to set JTextArea to fixed size

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea inside a JPanel. The JPanel is set to the default FlowLayout.

I assigned to the JTextArea a size through the constructor: `new JTextArea(50,50)`.

However, not only the size I specified is ignored once it's out of a certain range (for example, if I set the size to a value larger than 40*40, the program starts to ignore what I say and instead set the JTextArea to some arbitrary size) - the size also changes as I type. The JTextArea resizes itself if I type inside it more than it can contain.

I did:

`textArea.setLineWrap(true);`

Didn't solve this.

How can I set a fixed size for the JTextArea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you include it in a JScrollPane that might solve your problem :

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 50);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
```

You might also have to change you Layout, because by default I think it use the `BorderLayout` that expands your components. Or put it in `PAGE_START` like this :

```
add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(50, 50)), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Out of curiousoty, why doesn't setting the rows and columns properties work? It's supposed to, isn't it? Does it maybe depend on the layout manager?

Comment: I think colums and rows are just a preffered setting. May be try with the second proposition

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have fixed size, you have to put it inside a box like JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textarea);
```

if you want the text area to fit maximum number of letters:

```
textarea.setColumns(100);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution and say if it worked. Just curious, why doesn't the setting-size-through-constructor work? It's supposed to, isn't it? Does it maybe depend on the layout manager?

Comment: It also depends on you [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and width of the box (it can be fixed or scale-to-fit.

Comment: What do you mean by 'width of the box'? Do you mean the width of the JPanel containing the JTextArea?

Comment: @Prog Sorry, I took name 'box' from Qt ;) Yes, I meant a part of a layout, a grid in JGridBag or JBoxLayout. You can try JavaFX unless you don't need to run it on openjdk. It's easier to write, debug and design.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));`

Comment: setPreferredSize() won't work untill you have **proper** layout manager, so it's usually a bad idea to believe it will always work.

Comment: The preferred size of a `JTextArea` when added to a scroll pane comes from the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` method, which uses the rows and columns properties to calculate the size based on the current font metrics